# How to assign datalist to input in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off">

<datalist id="seek_list">
<option value="Value1">
<option value="Value2">
</datalist>
```

and this Javascript:

```
$('input[name=city]').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        $(this).attr('list', 'seek_list');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('list')
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNgRYv

I want the autocomplete to work after user types 2 or more chars in the input field. The datalist is not assigned in Firefox, but it works just fine in Chrome.
I'll just add that editing HTML of datalist is too slow as I have over 900 options in it.

So how to fix it for Firefox?

Comment: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2951249

Comment: It works in Firefox too, but only *after* you've typed more than 2 characters. This is an awkward way to go about restricting default behaviour... Just bind the list to the input declaratively (i.e., declare the `list="seek_list"` attribute in the markup directly) and forgo this weird dynamic assignment.

Comment: @AndréDion Doesn't work for me in 46.0.1 no matter how many chars I enter. I need this dynamically assigned because without it if you enter just 1 letter or none it shows a really long list and that's just looks bad.

Comment: "if you enter just 1 letter or none it shows a really long list and that's just looks bad" vs. showing absolutely nothing? I disagree. Users used to autocomplete behaviour know to reduce a large dataset by using more specific criteria, i.e., keep typing the term.

Comment: @AndréDion Generally I would agree with you. And because I like standard things I use input+datalist and not some fancy Javascript widgets that combine multiple divs, uls and whatever else. But in this case have a very limited space. Max I can show is 20 suggestions. I have found a solution that kinda works- I keep all the options in a Javascript array and onKeyUp I iterate through them and add only some of them to the datalist. Works in Firefox, works in Chrome and is fast.